# gcc optimization flags for strings handling (c++)

Tags: string, optimization, gcc, compiler-flags

I am looking for flags for strings handling that can improve my code speed. (I am not after something special, name and a short explanation will be just fine for me).

I am working with gcc

The only thing I found is:

> -fmerge-constants: Attempt to merge identical constants (string constants and floating-point constants) across compilation units. 
>   This option is the default for optimized compilation if the assembler
>   and linker support  it. Use -fno-merge-constants to inhibit this
>   behavior.  Enabled at levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os.

Comment: What kind of optimization are you after for "code speed" ?

Comment: `-fuse-better-algorithms`... no wait, this is still not implemented in gcc

Comment: @auselen what kinds exist?

Comment: since you are looking for flags I thought you are already aware of some optimizations. String handling is mostly memory operations. You should be precise with what's your problem. If you are looking for something general -O3 is what you want.